# Code completion in Toad

Tags: configuration, toad

I started developing in pl/sql recently. The IDE of choice is Taod. I quickly found out how to do codecompletion for tables, but I can't find a way to get code completion for variables.

I'm used to Textmate on the Mac where I simply write the beginning letters of a string and hit esc. The string is suplemented then with other strings from the same file which have the same beginning.

I was wondering if there is something like it in Taod, but I can't find it anywhere. I checked the checkbox next to *Available Variables/Parameteres* in *Code Assist -> Toad Insight Objects* but that didn't help.

Update: Toad Version 12.5.1.1. As pointed out in the first comment I did everything right, but it's actually a bug in this version of Toad.

Comment: What version of Toad are you on? That checkbox you tried is the way to go about it. There is a bug in Toad 12.5 (maybe earlier versions too) where it's not showing variables if they are defined in lowercase. If they are in uppercase it's OK. This is fixed in Toad 12.6 to be released soon.

Comment: @MichaelS. Thanks. I'm on 12.5.1.1. Your right, in upper case it's working fine, but I really don't like writing in upper case. Will wait for the next version.
If you phrase your comment as an answer here I'll tag it as the right one. Thx.

Comment: Thanks, done. 12.6 release date has not yet been set (as far as I know), but the fall release usually coincides with Oracle Open World which starts on Sept. 28. I'd look for Toad 12.6 sometime in the next month or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That checkbox you tried is the way to go about it. There is a bug in Toad 12.5 (maybe earlier versions too) where it's not showing variables if they are defined in lowercase. If they are in uppercase it's OK. This is fixed in Toad 12.6 to be released soon.